# How to load css from child theme last?

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I load my child theme's CSS last ? some other CSS files loads before my CSS and this is my current code to load my child theme's CSS. Thank you in advance!

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/roee.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
```

Comment: you might be able to just add priority to your `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );`

Comment: like `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 99);`

Comment: Did so, tried add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' , 99 ) and few more numbers..didn't help

Comment: maybe  `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);` ?

Comment: Tried.. no help :(